# How would I publish a 2D float Array through a ROS message?

Tags: ros, array, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working on a circle detection app. Using `OpenCV`, I get a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` named `v`. Now I want to send this to a different executable node. So I made a simple Circles.msg which is:

```
float32[][] circles
```

However, I get a bunch of errors, mostly which are:

```
'const class std::vector<std::vector<float> >' has no member named '__getMD5Sum'
```

From the line:

```
circle_pub_.publish(v);
```

which I get from:

```
ros::Publisher circle_pub_;
circle_pub_ = node.advertise("/circles", 1);
```

So therefore, I don't know how to approach this problem.

I also do not understand how to subscribe to this topic. Currently I got:

```
circles_in = node.subscribe("/circles", 1, organizer_callback);
void organizer_callback( const std::vector< std::vector<float> >& circles) {
    ....
}
```

Is this okay? Please let me know if you know any more information!

---

### The Code

Here is the most important parts of my program as of now:

```
class ImageConverter {
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
  image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
  image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;
  ros::Publisher circle_pub_;
  
public:
  ImageConverter()
    : it_(nh_)
  {

        // Subscribe to the Bottom Raw Image
        image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/ardrone/bottom/image_raw", 1, 
                &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);


        // Advertisng the Circles being detected from this 
                circle_pub_ =  nh_.advertise<zlab_drone::Circles>("/circles", 1);

  }

  void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
  {
       // Find the circles from a particular video  
       cv::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles; 
       cv::HoughCircles(img_bin, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 70, 140, 15, 
                    20, 400);


       std::vector<zlab_drone::Circle> v;

       for(int i = 0; i < circles.size(); ++i) {
           const cv::Vec3f& c = circles[i];
           v[i][0] = c[0];
           v[i][1] = c[1];
           v[i][2] = c[2];
       } 

       circle_pub_.publish(v);
     
    }
};
```

---

### Subscriber

Here's the code from my subscriber:

```
// Gathering Data from the messages
for (std::vector<zlab_drone::Circles>::const_iterator gp = 
    msg->circles.begin(); gp!= msg->circles.end(), ++gp) {
    for (std::vector<float>::const_iterator dp = 
        gp->circle.begin(); dp != gp->circle.end(); ++dp) {
        circles[gp][dp] = gp->circle(dp); 
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255306/how-would-i-publish-a-2d-float-array-through-a-ros-message?/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-23**:
Just a general comment: you can't publish/subscribe arbitrary datatypes, as you are trying to do, only *messages* (ie: specially crafted containers that are declaratively described in `.msg` files). @suforeman's answer shows how you could nest two such msgs to get a 2d array.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-23**:
@gvdhoorn Makes sense. However, when I implemented @suforeman's answer, I retained all the same errors.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-23**:
Well without seeing what you did *exactly*, it's hard to know what could be wrong, but I know from experience that what @suforeman suggests works.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-23**:
@gvdhoorn I have added the most relavant bits of code in the question now. I have also implemented what @suforeman has implemented.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-24**:
Your latest edit suggests you're still not using message definitions / classes, but `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-03-07**:
@gvdhoorn I still haven't understood how the publisher would be? I have edited the code to the most correct versions right now.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-03-07**:
You still appear to be trying to defining your topic subscriber without using your message definition. Compare your callback with the one in my answer's example. Try to get your subscriber working first. You can test your subscriber from the command line using `rostopic`.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-03-07**:
@ suforeman I have made the subscriber work exactly as you specified within your answer.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-03-07**:
What are your message definitions for Circles.msg and Circle.msg? If they are the same as my answer example, then `dp` is a vector of floats. It's not clear what you are attempting with `circles[gp][dp] = gp->circle(dp)`. Also, you code does not agree with the declaration.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-03-07**:
Compare my `void echo_groups (const groups::Groups::ConstPtr& msg)` callback vs your `void organizer_callback( const std::vector< std::vector<float> >& circles)`

It looks as though you are still not using message definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the method answered previously [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/67273/how-to-publish-a-two-dimensional-array-msg-with-int8-type/) or use a single array in conjunction with a step value (length of the rows) as is commonly done for 2D image data via something like [sensor_msgs/Image](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html).

For example (assuming row-major) element `circles[i][j]` would be at `data[i*step + j]`

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-23**:
I assume I wouldn't be getting any of the errors from above if I implement it this way, but I wanted a more object oriented solution to this problem. If I can't find anything by the end of today, I will have to accept and implement your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had my best success by decomposing the message definition.

Working example:

**Messages:**

```
Group.msg:
    float32[] data
Groups.msg:
    Group[] group
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(groups)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs message_generation)

add_message_files(DIRECTORY msg FILES Group.msg Groups.msg)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs message_runtime)

include_directories(include  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})


add_executable(groups src/groups.cpp)
target_link_libraries(groups ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(groups groups_generate_messages_cpp)

install(TARGETS groups
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION} 
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION} 
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION} 
)
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/ DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION} FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h" )
install(DIRECTORY launch/ DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch )
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/console.h>                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                       
// messages
#include "groups/Group.h"
#include "groups/Groups.h"
                                                                                                                                                                       
void echo_groups (const groups::Groups::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    for(std::vector<groups::Group>::const_iterator gp = msg->group.begin(); gp != msg->group.end(); ++gp) {
        for (std::vector<float>::const_iterator dp = gp->data.begin(); dp != gp->data.end(); ++dp)
            std::cout << *dp << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
                                                                                                                                                                       
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init (argc, argv, "groups");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber groups_sub = n.subscribe ("echo_groups", 8, echo_groups);
    ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

**Test:**

```
rostopic pub -1 /echo_groups groups/Groups "[data:[1.1, 1.2, 1.3], data:[2.1, 2.2, 2.3]]"
```

**Output:**

```
1.1 1.2 1.3 
2.1 2.2 2.3
```

---

Originally posted by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) with karma: 300 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-23**:
Can you please expand on your answer. Did you do anything special with the Publisher, or left it as is, in the question above?

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-23**:
I have also added a list of errors that I get, besides the main one, on the question.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-02-23**:
@sharan100 - I update my short answer with example code. It's not the prettiest but it does work.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-24**:
@suforeman This is an excellent way to subscribe, but how would you go about advertising?

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-24**:
Thanks btw!

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-24**:
@suforeman @gvdhoorn Could you please let me know how to approach the Publisher using these messages in the context of my question. I seem to be having quite a bit of problem making that happen.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-02-24**:
added CMakeLists.txt to answer

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-24**:
Oh, I've figured out what goes on in CMakeLists,txt. I am confused about the publisher right now @suforeman

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-03-07**:
@suforeman Still waiting on your answer about how the publisher would deal with this.